# "Sehr geehrte Dame, Sehr geehrter Herr"; mit oder ohne Komma

Tags: grammar, punctuation, salutation, letter

Ich verfasse eine Spontanbewerbung an meine aktuelle Firma, wo ich im Sommer meine Ausbildung beende.
Jetzt müssen alle Azubis eine Spontanbewerbung für die Firma schreiben. Weder für eine spezifische Stelle, noch an bestimmte Personen.

Da eine Bewerbung meist an eine bestimmte Person geht, ist für mich die `Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren` Klausel etwas zu unpersönlich. Deshalb möchte ich die unbekannte Person direkt ansprechen.

Jetzt stellt sich mir aber die Frage, kommt zwischen den beiden Teilen ein Komma, Zeilenabsatz oder wie genau soll dieser geschrieben werden? Meine aktuelle Version sieht wie folgt aus:

> Sehr geehrte Dame,
>   sehr geehrter Herr,
>
> mein Name (...)

Wird es jetzt mit/ohne Komma geschrieben, mit/ohne Zeilenabsatz, mit/ohne Kleinschreibung des zweiten `sehr`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Zunächst einmal, korrekt ist:

> Sehr geehrte Dame, sehr geehrter Herr,
>   ...

Danach folgt (beginnend mit einem Kleinbuchstaben) der Text.

> Da eine Bewerbung meist an eine bestimmte Person geht, ist für mich die Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren Klausel etwas zu unpersönlich. Deshalb möchte ich die unbekannte Person direkt ansprechen.

Das tust Du in deinem Beispiel aber nicht. *Sehr geehrte Dame, sehr geehrter Herr* ist nicht weniger unpersönlich.

Persönlicher wäre ausschließlich die direkte Anrede, also

> Sehr geehrte Frau Müller,

Zudem ist bei Bewerbungen üblicherweise die Anrede *Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren* zu verwenden.

Answer (score 6):

Eine Anrede in einem förmlichen Schreiben an eine Stelle, deren Mitarbeiter man persönlich nicht kennt, ist eindeutig geregelt:

> Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,

Das ist genau die Anredeformel, die auch ein Personalbüro in einer Bewerbung erwartet.

Man sollte in einem Bewerbungsschreiben nicht von einer solchen Anrede abweichen, denn man möchte doch auch zum Ausdruck bringen, dass man die übliche Form einer Korrespondenz kennt und sie anzuwenden weiß.

Auch kann man sich nahezu sicher sein, dass die Bewerbung von mehreren Personen gelesen werden wird, der Gebrauch des Singulars wäre dann sogar regelrecht falsch.

Nur wenn man den Chef/die Chefin oder eine andere Person, die Personalentscheidungen **alleine** trifft, namentlich kennt, kann man von der Regel abweichen und sie oder ihn direkt mit Namen anreden.

Comment: Ausführliche Begründung. Danke.

Comment: @dTDesign: vielleicht möchtest du lieber Thorstens Antwort als "accepted" markieren? Er sagt im Prinzip das selbe, aber er gibt uns zusätzlich auch eine Antwort auf deine Frage nach dem Komma.

Comment: Deinem letzten Absatz stimme ich nicht zu. Wenn das Schreiben an eine Ansprechperson im Unternehmen gerichtet ist, kann/soll durchaus die persönliche Anrede verwendet werden, auch wenn diese Person nicht *alleine* entscheidet.

Comment: Hab' sie gerade gelesen. Trotzdem danke für deine Antwort. +1

Comment: @Daniel: danke für den Hinweis, habe das mal abgeändert ;)

Comment: Hast du eine Referenz dafür, dass diese Anredeformel “ein Personalbüro in einer Bewerbung erwartet” und dass man “nicht von einer solchenAnrede abweichen” sollte?

Comment: @k.stm nur Mut, je nach Branche kann auch *Hey Leute* gehen. Ja, das sollte dann einwandfrei klappen.

Comment: @Takkat Also, arbeitest du im Personalbüro oder kennst viele Personaler oder  …?

Answer (score -2):

Es wird so geschrieben:

> Sehr geehrter Herr Müller,
>   mein Name …

*Sehr* wird großgeschrieben, weil es ein Satzanfang ist, und *mein* klein, weil es nach einem Komma kommt.

Comment: Wilkommen bei German.GLU! Was du sagst scheint, richtig zu sein. Trotzdem es beantwortet die Frage nicht.

Comment: @c.p. Schade um das verschwendete Komma :-)

Answer (score -3):

Mit Komma, weil es eine Auflistung ist, in einer Zeile, weil es sonst als diskriminierend empfunden werden könnte (sieht man schon, wenn man einfach mal Herren und Damen sagen würde).

Zweites großes *sehr* ist etwas schwammig:

Grammatisch gesehen muss es kleingeschrieben werden, wenn man allerdings sagt, dass der Leser jeweils seine passende Anrede "wählen" und den Rest ignorieren soll, dann würde ich es großschreiben.

Ich würde es großschreiben.

Comment: Es muss auf jeden Fall klein geschrieben werden. Es sind ganz normale Groß-/Kleinschreiberegeln anzuwenden.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Einerseits ja, Grammatik ist Grammatik,
aber bei Briefen (u.Ä.) schreibt man ja auch den Satz nach der Anrede trotz Komma groß. Ich würde in diesem Fall "Stil" vor Grammatik verwenden, aber das meine persönliche Präferenz.

Comment: Wo hast Du das mit der Großschreibung denn her!? Nach der Anrede im Brief wird mit Kleinschreibung begonnen, wenn die Anrede mit Komma endet. Endet die Anrede mit Ausrufezeichen, wird mit einem Großbuchstaben begonnen. Also ganz normal. Dass nach dem Komma mit Großbuchstaben begonnen wird ist Quatsch.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar, richtig. Wenn das jetzt noch jemand meinem Telefon beibringen würde...

Comment: @CarstenSchultz K9-Mail?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar, das benutze ich.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Genau das ärgert mich nämlich bei K9 auch *jedes Mal* mit dem Großbuchstaben...

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar, ich glaube, das ist bei allen so. Die Konvention ist im Englischen halt anders.